# The transparent static text in wxwidgets 3.0.2 is showing junk values before initialization?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl, wxformbuilder

I have few custom controls which show static text. These controls use to show zeros(0) in wx 2.8 version , now the same controls are showing some junk values when the application is launch and before its initialization. All these values in text control and filled dynamically based on user action.

How do I make it show default values like 0.0 or something in latest wxwidgets?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the text control when you invoke the constructor

```
new wxStaticText( this, -1, "0.0" );
```

For details of how and where to do this in your custom control, you will have to post your code : specifically the contructor code.

Comment: After further looking into my code,It shows the my custom control is derived from wxtextctrl, Though i pass wxT(" ") for value parameter in constructor it generates junk values. This was not the case in widgets 2.8 and its a unicode build

Comment: adding "0.0" in the constructor still gives junk values

Comment: @StraightCirle, also you can safely get rid of wxT(). This was needed in 2.8 where we had ANSI/UNICODE builds, but not needed anymore.